# Print out some columns to pdf

Tags: excel, vba

I want to print out only some specific columns to pdf but the gap between the columns I have selected prints out also. For example, I want columns A to D and H to print out on a pdf but they print out in two different pages.

My code is below:

```
Private Sub create_Click()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim num As Integer
    Dim start As String
    Dim top As Integer
    Const check As String = "ITEM"


    Set r = Range("A:A")
    For Each cell In r
        If cell.Value <> check Then
            top = top + 1
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
        
    num = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    start = "A" & top
    Worksheets("Liquidaciones").Range(start).AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:=corcom
    start = "A" & top & ":A" & num
    Set r = Range(start)
    
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .PrintArea = Intersect(Range("A:A,B:B,C:C,D:D,H:H"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange).Address
    .Orientation = xlLandscape
    .PrintGridlines = True
    .Zoom = False
    .FitToPagesTall = False
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    End With
    
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:="Z:\Personal\Report", _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=False, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=True
    
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: The idea is to filter out the columns and print them all on a single page but somehow they print out on two pages. A to D on one and H on an another

Comment: Maybe hide the columns you don't want to see, and then print?

Comment: tried that also but didn't work out

Comment: Did you set just the one range (A:H) for PrintArea?

Comment: my print area is "A:A,B:B,C:C,D:D,H:H"

Comment: Try A:H and hide the unwanted columns.

Comment: @TimWilliams I have one more question if you can help with this.
I wanted some data from userform to also appear on the pdf. Is it possible to add some data the user is giving in the userform in the pdf with the above data being printed?

Comment: Yes very possible but that sounds like a new post...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
.PrintArea = Intersect(Range("A:H"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange).Address
```

and then hide the unwanted columns before printing.